# Is there a way to throw an exception if the configuration xml file is not found in SSIS Package?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, configuration, etl, ssis-2012

I have an SSIS package (sql server 2012) which has a configuration xml file (dtsConfig). The path to the config is set by an environment variable. When executed using dtexec, and should the config file not be found in the expected location, the package runs regardless using the values in the package itself. Is there anyway to cause the package to immediately throw an exception if the dtsConfig is not found?

Answer (score 1):

If the configuration file doesn't exists the package will take the variables default values and throw a warning that the configuration file is missing.

You can add a script task that checks if the file exists. If it doesn't exist then it throws an exception.

#### Additional Information

- [SSIS 2008 Package Configurations being ignored](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35642/ssis-2008-package-configurations-being-ignored)
- [Check if a File exists in C#](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/check-if-a-file-exists-in-chash)

Comment: Though the provided first link doesn't answer the question, it is a very useful and helpful link, thanks. I don't think the second one can be used in my circumstance because I'm using environment variables - should have mentioned this..

Comment: @Excelnoobster you can access environment variables using script task (C#) .